# change the numbering in Beamer's table of content

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

Beamer's table of contents starts with bullet 1.  How can I change that to bullet 0?  The command \setcounter{section}{-1} in the preamble does not help.

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example i.e. the code for a small document demonstrating your problem. This will help people to understand and address your issue quickly and (hopefully) effectively. Note that by default there are no numbers or bullets at all.

Answer (score 10):

One would expect that setting `\beamer@tocsectionnumber=-1` would be enough (since `\beamer@tocsectionnumber` is the TeX counter controlling the section number typset in the ToC); however, this is not the case, since `\beamer@sectionintoc` (defined in `beamerbasetoc.sty`) has a conditional test using `\ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0` which won't allow typesetting non positive numbers in the ToC. The solution is to patch `\beamer@sectionintoc` and use as conditional test `\ifnum\beamer@tempcount>-1`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}
  {\ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0}
  {\ifnum\beamer@tempcount>-1}
  {}
  {}
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=-1
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First test section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\section{Second test section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\section{Third test section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I am looking for, without the patch, the number is just missing.